# I can't seem to get the right pattern displayed using for-loops?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get this pattern displayed by strictly using for-loops but I keep ending up with what you'll see under the code.

```
1*****
*2****
**3***
***4**
****5*
*****6
```

```
public class PA4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int line = 1; line <= 6; line++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (line - 1); j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print(line);
        for (int j = 1; j <= (line + 6); j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

```
1*******
*2********
**3*********
***4**********
****5***********
*****6************
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the pattern you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Dare I say: `System.out.print("1***** *2**** 3* *4 ****5* *****6");` since it's not clear what rules your pattern is following.

Comment: Write out the pattern: `line_num-1 stars, line_num, 6-line_num stars`...`line_num++`....repeat

Answer (score 2):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print(i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note** that `j <= (line - 1)` is the same as `j < line`, in your original code.

For any value of `n`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int n = 6;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (j == i) System.out.print(j+1);
      else System.out.print("*");
    }

    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

**Edit** now that I know you can *only* use for-loops, let's think about it like this:

```
int n = 6;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // iterate from 0 to < i, printing an *

    // now we're at i, so we just print our number (which is i+1)

    // now we go back to iterating, from i+1 to <n
    // (continuing where we left off)

    // finally, print a newline since we're done with this row
  }
```

Comment: I'm only allowed to use for loops to display this output. It's a beginner's java course and I haven't learned about "if" and "else" yet.

Comment: @maltuin ah. That might be something you want to specific in your original question. And since it's a beginner course I'm more hesitant to just post the answer. I'd recommend pen and paper and translating the logic of my working code into for loops.

Comment: I started out by breaking down similar code he did on a slide in class by using charts, and I thought I had it figured out, but I've been stuck trying for over an hour. Do you have a method I can use to start from the bottom and work my way up? I want to understand what I'm doing, not just be given answers.

Comment: @maltuin see my edit - a good strategy is try to explain to yourself what needs to happen in plain English - then translate the English to psuedocode, and finally, psuedocode to java .

Comment: I'm gonna keep working on this. My professor also just mentioned explaining in English and then pseudocode last class. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 1; j <= (line + 6); j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
```

Replace your second for loop with the following code -

```
for (int j = (line + 1); j <= 6; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
```

https://logicblocks.blogspot.com

Comment: In the second for loop, your iterations are more than 6.